# How I can get specific values from Matlab Figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to get some specific values from a Matlab Figure. The number of values can be 3, 5, 10, 50 or any N integer. Like in sample pictures,

[image: Pic1] [image: Pic2]

I want to get values of A, B, C. in form of e.g A=(430,0.56).

A,B,C are not the part of Plot. I just wrote them in Photoshop help clarify the question.

**Note: On every execution of the code input values can be different.**

**The length of the input values (Graph Values) can also change every time.**

Comment: What are those points (A, B, C) etc? Are they actually plotted as a separate series? Check out the `ginput` function if they are not marked on the chart already

Comment: A,B,C or not the part of Plot. I just Wrote them in Photoshop to make Understand the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hc=get(gca,'children');
data=get(hc,{'xdata','ydata'});
t=data{1};
y=data{2};
tA=250;tB=1000; %tA is starting Point and tB is the last point of data as ur figure
yinterval=y(t>=tA & t<=tB);
display(yinterval);
```

**Try this code, Its working for me** Code is according to Time and Y figure.

Comment: Some explanation would improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

First open the figure, then obtain the x and y coordinates of the line with

```
line = get(gca, 'Children');   % Get the line object in the current axis of the figure.
x = get(line, 'XData');   % Get the abscissas.
y = get(line, 'YData');   % Get the ordinates.
```

To obtain the value `yi` at the point with abscissa greater or equal then `xi` you can write

```
id = find(x>=xi, 1, 'first');   % On the opposite try find(x<=xi, 1, 'last');
yi = y(id);
```

Or you can do a linear interpolation

```
yi = interp1(x, y, xi);
```

To extract the values between the points with abscissa `x1` and `x2` you can follow both strategies. With the first you could write

```
ids = find(x>=x1 & x<=x2);
xReduced = x(ids);   % A subset of x.
yReduced = y(ids);   % A subset of y.
```

The first line intersects the set of points that follow `x1` with the set of points that precede `x2`, and the return the indices. If you choose to interpolate tou can construct a new set of points, and interpolate over that set.

```
xReduced = x1:step:x2;   % As an alternative you can use linspace(x1, x2, nPoints);
yReduced = interp1(x, y, xReduced);
```

Comment: and what if i want to take range of values form Point A to B ?

Comment: But you did not explained the code. like what is "xi"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tought that the code was self explanatory. I have added some comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a chart and you just want to find out the values of arbitrary points on the chart you can use the [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) function or by far the simplest solution is to just use the **interactive [data cursor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html)** built into the figure window.