# How can I extract data in a vector from semilogx figure?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, transfer-function, loglog

How can I extract data in a vector from `semilogx` figure?
I am using `bode` plot to identify a system transfer function so I need the two vectors coming from `semilogx` graph to compare slope and identify system from approximate solution.

Is there any other method to do this identification?[I wanna get the slope of this figure so i need xy data from this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0skbF.jpg)

Comment: Neither the input nor the expected result are clear. Please provide demo plotting code [in the body of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42976475/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you asking specifically semilogx plot? When you get the data from a figure, you access the data directly as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25322229/7659682). What am I missing here?

```
hc=get(gca,'children');
data=get(hc,{'xdata','ydata'});
x=data{1};
y=data{2};
```

Comment: your code give data i already had ,
i want data from the figure as i think semilog creates a function between x and y and i do not have that function  ( it is different using  semilog than plot) @Ozcan